# Using Lift's snippet processing outside of Lift

Tags: scala, code-snippets, lift

Is there a way to use Lift's snippet processing outside the normal request handling process? I know I can call `LiftSession.findAndProcessTemplate`, but that obviously requires an instance of `LiftSession`. Is there a way to do that without LiftSession as long as I only use stateless snippets? Alternatively, is there a way to get an "empty" instance of `LiftSession`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you can use net.liftweb.http.S.runTemplate:

http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4-M4/#net.liftweb.http.S

Comment: Ah, thanks! Couldn't find that. Can I use Lift's standard snippets (like surround) with that? What about implicit snippet binding via reflection? If you don't know off the top of your head, I'll just try.

Comment: iirc surround should work OK, don't really understand what you mean by implicit binding reflection but you can use any binding you want.